# What is the scope of DIVA-GIS geodata that are available for download?

Tags: license, diva-gis

In the 'Free Spatial Data' download section it says the geodata is "free" - is there a concrete license? Is it public domain, creative commons? Can it be used for commercial purposes?

When I download it, there is an attached license text file that says: "*These data were extracted from the GADM database (www.gadm.org), version 2.5, July 2015. They can be used for non-commercial purposes only.  It is not allowed to redistribute these data, or use them for commercial purposes, without prior consent.*"

Comment: If the license file states all these conditions then all of your questions are answered, aren't they? There is a concrete license. It is not public domain or Creative Commons. And you can't use it for commercial purposes.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Actually, diva-gis was mentioned in couple of websites as a place to contain free reusable maps, which is why I wanted to confirm. They could mention the same in their download page, that its not totally free.

Comment: "Free" has a number of meanings. It's not wrong, just not what you intended.